# GNU Prolog: Displaying WAM code for query?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog, warren-abstract-machine

Is it possible to display the WAM code for a query using [GNU Prolog](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/)?

I know I can use pl2wam to generate the WAM for the program, but what about the queries I perform on the program? Is there a way to show the WAM code for this?

I'm using version 1.4.4 for x64 Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries are not compiled to WAM code. They are meta-interpreted on the fly by the top-level (so no WAM code is produced). To see the WAM code which would be generated by the compiler create a file with a clause whose head contains all name variables of the query and the body corresponds to the query.
For instance for the query:

```
?- append(X,Y,[a,b,c]).
```

create a Prolog file containing

```
query(X,Y) :- append(X,Y,[a,b,c]).
```

and compile it to a WAM file to see the result.